# How to stop Windows Update from being autodisabled at each restart? (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

Each time I restart my computer, Windows Update gets disabled. I've already scanned for malware and didn't find any. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In order to check that your Windows Update service is set for automatic start, perform the following steps:

1. Run `services.msc`
2. Locate and enter `Windows Update` service in the services list
3. Check the "Startup type"

There are 4 Startup types:

- Automatic
- Manual
- Disabled

You need to choose **Automatic**

Comment: Yes, its already automatic, and its started, but a red shield with a white cross appears in the bottom right corner of my screen saying windows update are disabled. When I double-click on it, it opens windows security center where I can see automatic updates are disabled. When I click on "activate", the red shield disappears.